# How to write a Prolog rule to define a predicate?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

here's the assignment: In a Prolog program, predicates are defined:

- `mother(M,Y)` — **M** is the mother of **Y**
- `father(F,X)` — **F** is the father of **X**

Write Prolog code to implement the predicate:

- `cousins(X,Y)` — **X** and **Y** are cousins
- `brother_or_sister(X,Y)` — **X** and **Y** are brother or sister of each other.

My attempts:

```
mother(m1, nicolas).
father(f1,nicolas).

mother(m2, mark).
father(f2, mark).

father(f3, f1).
mother(m3, f1).
father(f3, f2).
mother(m3, f2).

brother_or_sister(X, Y) :-
    father(f3, X),
    father(f3, Y),
    mother(m3, X),
    mother(m3, Y).

cousins(X, Y) :-
    (
      mother(m1, X),
      father(f1, X),
      mother(m2, Y),
      father(f2, Y)
    )
    (
      (
        brother_or_sister(m1, m2) ;
        brother_or_sister(f1, f2)
      )
      ;
      (
        brother_or_sister(f1, m2) ;
        brother_or_sister(m1, f2)
      ).
```

Program output:

```
true
false
```

Although it's supposed to be true

Please help!

Comment: Google shows examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=prolog+mother+father+cousin

Comment: Going to point out that your sample code is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brothers and sisters are *siblings*. Two people are *siblings* if they have common parentage (and *half-siblings* if they share just one common parent). So we can say things like:

```
parents(F:M,X) :- mother(M,X), father(F,X) . 

sibling(X,Y) :- parents(F:M,X), parents(F:M,Y) .
```

Similarly, two people are *cousins* if they have parents who are *siblings* of each other. That leads to:

```
parent(P,X) :- father(P,X) .
parent(P,X) :- mother(P,X) .

cousin(X,Y) :- parent(Px,X), parent(Py,Y), sibling(Px,Py) .
```